# Complete Edit Form refresh in C# code

Tags: edit-form

I'm back with another problem. ;)

I managed to create a list with a multi lookup to another list, containing some labels.
I added a webpart to list A's edit form to allow direct adding of labels to List B, with the intention of the added values showing up in the lookup immediatly.

First, I try to add a new label by filling in the textbox and clicking Create, as shown here:
http://imgur.com/2duDbM3,hB8OCFo#2

However, the page then reloads, showing the lookup columns to be both empty, like here:
http://imgur.com/2duDbM3,hB8OCFo#1

Is there anyway I can force a full refresh of the page via C# code behind the Create button that will make this page show up correctly?

Thanks in advance!
David

Comment: Whats the version of your SharePoint? I would really suggest if possible stay away from server side code use JSOM/CSOM to customize your sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

You can always hook to a button press event via JavaScript\JQuery and refresh your page.

Example:

Hook to a click event and refresh the page:

```
$("#target").click(function() {
  location.reload();
});
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the tip.
However, the reload() function gives the user a dialog asking to resend the information. In this case, they'd create the new label twice, while they're supposed to be unique. I've tried using "window.location.href=window.location.href;", that does give me the same page with the controls filled, but in the state that is was -before- adding the new label. The created label doesn't show up in the available labels column yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

Call `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);` at the end of your method. This will cause you to redirect to a fresh load of the page.